# How do I find the build dependencies of a package?

Tags: command-line, dependencies

I'd like to find out which packages

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
```

would install (if I already got some dependencies installed, I'd also like to see those → so running or simulating the above is not enough). Command line preferred.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>` show the list of packages (if the package has any build dependencies) it is going to install?

Comment: Unfortunately that only shows packages that aren't installed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For a *full list* of dependencies, including the dependencies' dependencies, you can use:

```
apt-rdepends --build-depends openoffice.org
```

The command may remind you to install `apt-rdepends` first.

You can use the following command to only show the ones that are not installed:

```
apt-rdepends --build-depends --print-state openoffice.org | grep NotInstalled
```

See `apt-rdepends --help` for all the options.

**Note**: This will generate a *massive* list.
`apt-rdepends -b xterm`, for example, generates 8773 lines of output, and takes it's time doing it.

If you only want to see the packages that are required to build the topmost package, i.e. what do I need to install to build nautilus, run:

```
apt-rdepends --build-depends --follow=DEPENDS nautilus
```

This is roughly equivalent to Carsten Thiel's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21379/how-do-i-find-the-build-dependencies-of-a-package/21388#21388) (`The following NEW packages will be installed`), but the output format is a bit nicer. It also only shows the topmost package, whereas simulated apt-get also shows packages installed as dependencies of those.

This also shows packages that are installed. But it may also show packages that are installed by default. Unfortunately, neither method is much help when you're trying to *clean up* your system after running apt-get build-dep. As far as I know, there isn't a reliable method of finding which ones were installed except from looking at the apt log file at **`/var/log/apt/history.log`**.

Comment: Thanks, the version with `--follow=DEPENDS` is exactly what I was looking for. You can also find those build dependencies on Launchpad, eg. for Nautilus: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/nautilus (scroll down).

Comment: Yeah, but `apt-rdepends -b foo` does not seem to "de-duplicate", so several packages will end up multiple times in the list.

Comment: While the version with `--follow=DEPENDS` works for me, `DEPENDS` seem to exploit a bug in apt-rdepends, namely, that it acceps anything case-sensitivly after `--follow`, with `DEPENDS` not being a valid symbol. For instance, `--follow=none` or `--follow=Chuck-Norris` do the same thing.

Answer (score 24):

```
apt-cache showsrc <pkgname> | grep ^Build-Depends
```

`showsrc` displays the debian/control file for a given source package. We then grep for the line(s) which begin with 'Build-Depends' which has the list of packages needed to build from source.

Comment: +1 if you explain what `apt-cache showsrc` and what `|` `grep` does. Still, good answer. Thanks for taking the time to provide it.

Comment: `sudo apt-cache showsrc inkscape` doesn't work for `inkscape` in Ubuntu 18.10 - gives
`W: Unable to locate package inkscape
N: No packages found`

Comment: @anatolytechtonik just tested on Ubuntu 18.10 in Docker, works for me. Did you `apt-get update` first?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it provides the needed tool and does not need any extra package.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon Unfortunately it doesn't parse conditional dependencies or version requirements, both of which would affect what is actually installed by the `build-dep` command.

Answer (score 16):

The option `-s` (`--simulate`) will output everything that would be done without doing anything. You don't even need root privileges for that.

```
apt-get -s build-dep <package>
```

Comment: See my comment above - this won't show already installed packages. Sorry for not being precise in my question.

Comment: Doesn't work - fails with `E: Unable to find a source package for inkscape`