# How do I build Nautilus 3.70/3.80 from source?

Tags: nautilus, dependencies

I've upgraded nautilus on my PC to 3.60 with the nice sidebar, but I'm finding the lack of recursive search difficult. I've downloaded Nautilus 3.7.5 and 3.7.1 which have replaced the recursive search but it wont compile. Lots of missing package errors.

I was surfing on my ipad while out and I came across a page that listed all the ubuntu dependencies for Nautilus 3.7.x and foolishly forgot to bookmark it.

Rather than painstakingly `./configure` ing multiple times and installing the `lib####` files one by one after a cache search does anyone either know a better way or where I could find that list of dependencies again. Thanks.

This is one of the messages from one of the packages that is missing. `libtracker-sparql-0.14` is the latest in the ubuntu repositories and `tracker-0.15` is the latest in the gnome git repository. I'm okay with downloading that one and trying to install it but would like to put a list together of all the dependencies or find one if someone has already done so, so that this can be installed easily.

```
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: Package requirements (tracker-sparql-0.16) were not met:

No package 'tracker-sparql-0.16' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables TRACKER_CFLAGS
and TRACKER_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

the base dependencies are listed on the following page

[gnome nautilus developer page](https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development/Nautilus)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the build dependencies of a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21379/how-do-i-find-the-build-dependencies-of-a-package)

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCastro, I did find that question before asking here, but it seems to cover packages already supported by ubuntu/aptitude, not a beta build which is currently unsupported. I'm not sure why this is deemed off topic. `Raring` comes with Nautilus 3.60 and doesn't have recursive search. Nautilus 3.70/3.80 have reinstated it and there is already a quite vocal protest against 3.60 evident among users posting in the forums. Knowing how to add back this functionality in an efficient way is likely to be pretty relevant to a lot of Ubuntu users now and when `Raring` goes into production.

Comment: ok I've retitled your question to be more specific, and voted to reopen

Comment: Please add the results of your ./configure and stuff too to your question.

Comment: thanks @JorgeCastro. added and edited. Not sure how to upload the whole config file. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Just that is fine, I ran into the exact same issue with the sparql thing, still investigating ...

Comment: Try install nautilus 3.8.1 from [gnome3 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3?field.series_filter=raring). If u want to compile, get the source (from the same ppa) of tracker & nautilus (with `dget -x link-to-dsc`  && `dpkg -x dsc-file`) & then have a look inside rules/control files, & how they have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://live.gnome.org/Nautilus/Development/Nautilus

The install notes, referenced in the README text of the nautilus 3.8 version source-code. 
It lists dependencies, and gives installation instructions.

You may want to read the README file in the source code folder.

Comment: Broken link and nothing in the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem by installing a package using apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install libtracker-sparql-0.16-dev.
```

If this gives a further set of errors as in [Is there any way to Install Latest Nautilus File Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344370/is-there-any-way-to-install-latest-nautilus-file-manager-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts), Then add the repository mentioned there and it solved the problem for me.