# Totem 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, totem

Can I upgrade Totem to version 3.6.3 in Ubuntu 12.04 without the webupd8 ppa. I tried the process from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413870/gedit-3-6-3-in-ubuntu-12-04/414038#414038), but I have some problems with getting the dependencies. The Reason why I want Totem 3.6.3 is of course for the latest changes and speed improvements.

The solution by `Wilf` doesn't work! This is what happened when I followed the procedure:

```
david@david-VirtualBox:~$ wget
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/136994659/totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
--2014-02-01 14:54:55--  http://launchpadlibrarian.net/136994659/totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
Resolving launchpadlibrarian.net (launchpadlibrarian.net)...
91.189.89.229, 91.189.89.228 Connecting to launchpadlibrarian.net (launchpadlibrarian.net)|91.189.89.229|:80... connected. HTTP request
sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 104032 (102K)
[application/x-debian-package] Saving to:
`totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb'

100%[======================================>] 104,032     --.-K/s   in
0.005s  

2014-02-01 14:54:56 (18.2 MB/s) - `totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb'
saved [104032/104032]

david@david-VirtualBox:~$ sudo dpkg -i totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for david:  (Reading database ... 238277 files and
directories currently installed.) Preparing to replace totem 3.4.3-0ubuntu1~precise1 (using totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement totem ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of totem:
totem depends on libcogl12 (>= 1.7.4); however: Package libcogl12 is not installed.
totem depends on libtotem0 (>= 3.6.3-0ubuntu6); however: Version of libtotem0 on system is 3.4.3-0ubuntu1~precise1.
totem depends on gstreamer1.0-clutter; however: Package gstreamer1.0-clutter is not  installed.
totem depends on gstreamer1.0-plugins-base (>= 0.11.93); however: Package gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is not installed.
totem depends on gstreamer1.0-plugins-good (>= 0.11.93); however: Package gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is not installed.
totem depends on gstreamer1.0-x; however:  Package gstreamer1.0-x is not installed. 
totem depends on totem-common (= 3.6.3-0ubuntu6); however: Version of totem-common on system is 3.4.3-0ubuntu1~precise1.
dpkg: error processing totem (--install):  dependency problems - leaving
unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ... Rebuilding
/usr/share/applications/bamf.index... Processing triggers for
gnome-menus ... Errors were encountered while processing:  totem
```

And I get errors from the `sudo apt-get build-dep totem`

```
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get build-dep totem
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done The following packages have unmet
dependencies:
librsvg2-dev : Depends: librsvg2-2 (= 2.36.1-0ubuntu1) but 2.36.3-0ubuntu1~precise1 is to be installed
libtotem-plparser-dev : Depends: libtotem-plparser17 (= 3.4.1-1) but 4.2-1~precise1 is to be installed
Depends: gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 (= 3.4.1-1) but 3.4.2-1~precise1 is to be installed E: Build-dependencies for totem could not be satisfied. david@david-
VirtualBox:~/Downloads$
```

I seem to get errors from installing the depedencies that `Wilf` suggested, I did uninstall them before installing the newer version. Here is what I got in the terminal:

```
david@david-VirtualBox:~$ cd ~/Downloads/
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i totem-common_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_all.deb 
[sudo] password for david: 
Selecting previously unselected package totem-common.
(Reading database ... 269477 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking totem-common (from totem-common_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_all.deb) ...
Setting up totem-common (3.6.3-0ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i libtotem0_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package libtotem0.
(Reading database ... 269887 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libtotem0 (from libtotem0_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtotem0:
 libtotem0 depends on libcogl12 (>= 1.7.4); however:
  Package libcogl12 is not installed.
 libtotem0 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0 on system is 2.34.1-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0.
dpkg: error processing libtotem0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libtotem0
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i libcogl12_1.14.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package libcogl12.
(Reading database ... 269896 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libcogl12 (from libcogl12_1.14.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcogl12:
 libcogl12 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.15-0ubuntu10.5.
 libcogl12 depends on libegl1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) | libegl1-x11; however:
  Package libegl1-mesa is not installed.
  Package libegl1-x11 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libcogl12 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcogl12
```

Looks like I'm missing some dep's, and the `libglib2.0-0` on my system `(2.34.1)` is newer than what is on the raring page `(2.33.14)` and it says I need `2.35.9,` looks like I have to dig in Saucy's or Trusty's page for `libglib2.0-0 v.2.35`. Ok I checked, Saucy is using just the exact same version of `libglib2.0-0` as raring as its still `2.33.14`. However Trusty is using `2.39.3`, and I'm using `2.34.1`, so what should I use?

EDIT

Ignore what I said like they put the wrong version number in the description but when you go on the page it's actually `2.36.0` for Raring, `2.38.0` for Saucy, and `2.39.3` for Trusty. So should I just go with `2.36.0` or should I get `2.35.9`? Wouldn't `2.36.0` work as well? I'm going to go with v.`2.35.9` found [here.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/2.35.9-2ubuntu1)

Ok, all these dependencies are leading to more dependencies, and it looks like an infinite loop, and Synaptic can't remove the broken packages anymore! I'll start with a backup of my Virtual Machine before I started upgrading Totem again then I can be assisted again.

Gdebi seems not to like Totem 3.6.3 ether because of the mozilla-totem plugin.

```
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  indicator-printers gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 libdiscid0 unity-lens-video
  linux-headers-3.2.0-56 unity-scope-video-remote gir1.2-json-1.0
  librhythmbox-core5 libpcrecpp0 linux-headers-3.2.0-56-generic
  language-pack-kde-en kde-l10n-engb libcmis-0.2-0 libmusicbrainz3-6
  libpcre3-dev language-pack-kde-en-base gir1.2-xkl-1.0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdebi-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 159 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,198 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe gdebi-core all 0.8.5build1 [159 kB]
Fetched 159 kB in 1s (139 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package gdebi-core.
(Reading database ... 238277 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gdebi-core (from .../gdebi-core_0.8.5build1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up gdebi-core (0.8.5build1) ...
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Breaks existing package 'totem-mozilla' dependency totem (= 3.4.3-0ubuntu1~precise1)
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$
```

And when I install totem-mozilla 3.6.3:

```
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi totem-mozilla_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: totem (= 3.6.3-0ubuntu6)
```

Ok so how do I install Totem 3.6 + all the dependencies needed without breaking any packages?

Comment: But, similar as your linked as answer state, does Totem `3.6.3` exist :D. What is your current version of totem? You may be able to use `totem --version` command to find it, if not Open Totem, and go to Help > About.

Comment: Yes: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/totem look at the latest version on that page, it's 3.6.3-0ubuntu6 if I'm not mistaken. Also my current version of Totem is 3.4.3

Comment: That's for 13.04... You may be able to install it - are you using 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 64 bit (x86_64)

Comment: But I also have a 32bit (i686) netbook too (If it goes well I'll do it on it too, So both)

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/totem_3.6.3.orig.tar.xz = sources to use with the first link you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `.deb` for `3.6.3` from [here for 64bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/totem/3.6.3-0ubuntu6), or [here for 32bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/i386/totem/3.6.3-0ubuntu6), and install it with Software Center. You may also be able to install it with these commands:

**64bit:**

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/136994659/totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

**32bit:**

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/136992776/totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_i386.deb
```

The advantage of this is that you  don't have to compile anything, as in your linked answer. The disadvantage is it might not have the right dependencies, so you might have to download those as well from [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas), or [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/video/totem).

<sub>I ain't running any machines currently with 12.04, so I can't test this answe,r but it should work. If the none of the above packages are for the right architecture *(32bit/64bit/powerpc/whatever)*, You should be able to find them [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+package/totem)</sub>

Comment: Ok, I'll test it in a VM first like always! Then do it to my systems! Thank you

Comment: OK. Hopefully if it was to cause any problems, it would tell you first - but `apt...` does not always notice... :-) . If its in a VM, the package state may be different, so it might install differently.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :( Here is what I did:

Comment: Maybe I should try the one that I have to compile. I think that should work

Comment: What was the problem? - the previous comment said `Here is what I did:`...

Comment: It was the terminal and it didn't fit and it didn't let me edit out. It was just the grey highlighted stuff, Idk I'm only ok at the terminal so I can't really find what I did wrong but I think its 2 dep's that are in newer versions I think. Now looking over it looks like I'm missing dep's but the sudo apt-get build-dep totem command refuses to get the dep's so Idk whats going on :( I need help with this

Comment: Probably - `totem` is integral to Gnome, and sort of Unity, as it is one of the things that does the thumbnails of video files etc. You can get it to fit by going to terminal preferences and setting 'Scrolling' to 'Unlimited'.

Comment: And how do you do that if I may ask? Thanks in advanced

Comment: Btw, I'm using Gnome Fallback / Classic, but I doubt that's the problem

Comment: Oh I see yes I did set it to unlimited in the terminal, so now what?

Comment: But isn't it already in the question?

Comment: Ok. You shoudld be able to sort out `gstreamer` errors by running `sudo apt-get install gstreamer*`. Remove `libcogl12`, `libtotem0` and `totem-common`, and install the versions mentioned - [`totem-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/totem-common), [`libcogl12`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libcogl12), [`libtotem0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libtotem0).

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be getting errors when installing the deps. I'll put what I got in the terminal in the q

Answer (score 0):

The method to install it is simple. Just use Gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi totem_3.6.3-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
```

That's all. Now, you could also build it from source if necessary.

Comment: Ok, I will try it when I have time!

Comment: Wait, you said I can build it from source, does that mean that gdebi supports .orig.tar.xz (or just .tar.xs) files too?

Comment: Gdebi says that its uninstallable, I'll post the terminal stuff in the answer.

Comment: You already have totem mozilla, why you want to install the other totem? Also, if you don't want totem mozilla, just remove it.

Comment: Oh ok I'll try then. But totem-mozilla is a dependence.