# Is it possible to "trick" PPA's to think you have installed 12.10 while actually running 12.04?

Tags: ppa, software-installation

I've been [having some trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414188) manually installing packages and so I was wondering if I can "trick" the GNOME 3 team's PPA to think I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, so I can install GNOME 3.6 software easily on Ubuntu 12.04.

Once it's done, though, I do want to change it back to 12.04 instead of the "fake" 12.10.

So, what this boils down to: **How can I temporarily change my version identifier?**

Comment: Is there any reason why instead of using 13.10 which has GNOME 3.10 you are trying to mess with your package management?

Comment: @Braiam 13.10 is only good for 9 months not 5 years.

Comment: There's 14.04 around the corner with 5 year support too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try adding the PPA the "normal" way (sudo add-apt-repository). Before running `sudo apt-get update`, I would open the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, and look for a file who's title resembles the ppa you added. As a root user, open the file with your favorite text editor, and replace all instances of the word **precise**, with **quantal**. Then, run `sudo apt-get update`, and install your desired packages. From there, change your ppa back, (or re-add with add-apt-repository), and run `sudo apt-get update`, to prevent other potentially problematic packages from installing.