# How do I remove project-specific development packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm on vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36 desktop.

Back in the day, I thought I would [attempt compiling gnome-shell from source](https://askubuntu.com/q/1319108/1157519), and accordingly, I have installed a bunch of dev dependencies.

Now however my system partition is getting short on space, and I have no intent of building gnome-shell any more.

How could I efficiently remove those dev dependencies that I installed in context of this project?

This seems to be the list I installed manually:

```
meson
gcc
cmake
libecal2.0-dev
libgcr-3-dev
libgirepository1.0-dev
libgjs-dev
libmutter-6-dev
libpolkit-agent-1-dev
libstartup-notification0-dev
libgnome-desktop-3-dev
libgnome-bluetooth-dev
libnm-dev
xsltproc
sassc
libpulse-dev
asciidoc-base
```

Also, they had a whole bunch of additional dependencies to them.

Do I need to excerciese extra care when removing these (and *their* dependencies)? As in: could my system get destabilized whlie removing their dependencies?

I expect there will be several dozen, if not over a hundred packages to be removed...

Comment: Look through the logs in `/var/log/apt/`. You can see when, and in which order, packages were installed.